# Copy layout from another widget

Tags: qt, qlayout

I have so when a person clicks a button it should duplicate a tab but I have run into the problem that `tab->layout()` only returns `QLayout` and I can't convert it `QHBoxLayout`.

```
void MainWindow::on_dublicateSection_clicked()
{
    QWidget* tab = tabWidget->currentWidget();

    QWidget* newTab = new QWidget(tab);

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(tab->layout());
    newTab->setLayout(layout);

    content->IncreaseArraySize(Section(tabWidget->count()));

    QString tabText = tabWidget->tabText(tabWidget->currentIndex());
    content->sections[tabWidget->count()].name = tabText;
    tabWidget->addTab(newTab,tabText);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can.

```
QHBoxLayout* hbLayout = qobject_cast<QHBoxLayout*>(tab->layout());
Q_ASSERT(hbLayout);
```

But keep in mind that `QObject` derived classes are ***NOT*** copyable.